# Bit strings, $\omega$, $\lambda$ - need help interpreting and describing

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

## Problem

For these recursive definitions of sets of bit strings, show 5 elements from each set, and identify what set it is (in a few words).

## Attempt

### 1

- Basis: $1 \in S_!$
- Recursion: $\omega \in S_1 \rightarrow 1\omega \in S_1$
- Five Elements: $1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111$
- Description: *A string of 1's from length 1 to infinity.*

### 2

- Basis: $1 \in S_2$
- Recursion: $\omega \in S_2 \rightarrow 0\omega \in S_2 \wedge 1\omega \in S_2$
- Five Elements: 1, 01, 11, 001, 101, 011, 111, ...
- Description: *A string of 0's and 1's from length 1 to infinity, not ending in 0.*

**No idea how to do the following. What is $\lambda$?**

### 3

- Basis: $\lambda \in S_3$
- Recursion: $\omega \in S_3 \implies 0\omega1 ∈ S_3$

### 4

- Basis: $\lambda \in S_4$
- Recursion: $\omega \in S_4 \implies 0\omega \in S_4 \land \omega1 \in S_4$

### 5

- Basis: $\lambda \in S_5 \land 1 \in S_5$
- Recursion: $\omega ∈ S_5 \implies \omega0 \in S_5 \land \omega01 \in S_5$

---

My book didn't even cover this topic, neither did the prof. cover it in class.

Will someone please:

1. Verify if I wrote the descriptions for 1 and 2 correct (and provide an example if incorrect)?
2. Tell me the meaning of $\lambda$?
3. And give examples of how to interpret / solve 3 through 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, $\lambda$ denotes the empty string, namely the string with no characters. For your question (3), then, we have $\lambda\in S_3$ so concatenating a $0$ on the left and $1$ on the right (of nothing) yields $01\in S_3$. Questions (4) and (5) are done similarly.

Your first two solutions are correct.

**Added**. By the way, a fair number of authors use $\epsilon$ instead of $\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir.  What is the purpose of this?

Comment: @positiveimpact. What is "this"? Are you asking what is the purpose of the exercise, the purpose of $\lambda$, the purpose of recursive definitions of a language, or the purpose of life?

Comment: Is this correct: Example elements in $S_3$: 01, 0011, 000111, 00001111, 0000011111, ...

Description: A string of 0's and 1's, where the first half of the string consists of 0's and the second half of 1's, and the number of 0's equals the number of 1's, ranging in length from 1 to infinity. - What is the purpose of this exercise? - Also, How would I describe the elements in $S_4$?  Is this correct for elements in $S_4$: 0, 1, 00, 11, 01, 000, 011, 001, 111, ...?

Comment: Almost. For $S_3$ you have your answer *and* the empty string (namely the string starting with no $0$s and ending with no $1$)s. For $S_4$ the language consists of all strings starting with $k$ zeros followed by $j$ ones, where $0\le k, j$. The purpose of the exercise is to get you used to dealing with definitions and descriptions of languages of strings, something you'll be doing a *lot* in the future.

Comment: " For S4 the language consists of all strings starting with k zeros followed by j ones"  but $S_4$ can start with 1, correct?  Did you mean to describe $S_3$?

Comment: And thanks again.

Comment: @positiveimpact. In $S_4$ if we take $k=0, j=1$ we get $\omega=1$. All the $1$s are added to the right and all the $0$s are added to the left.